# How to exclude 'UNLIMITED TABLESPACE' from 'RESOURCE' privilege in Oracle

Tags: oracle

After I create the user TEMP_USER with default and temp tablespace, then I grant the user with following

```
GRANT CONNECT TO TEMP_USER;
GRANT RESOURCE TO TEMP_USER;
GRANT CREATE ANY VIEW TO TEMP_USER;
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY DATA_PUMP_DIR TO TEMP_USER;
GRANT advisor to TEMP_USER;
GRANT administer sql tuning set to TEMP_USER;
GRANT CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW to TEMP_USER;
```

Then when execute

```
select * from session_privs;
```

I get all these privileges to current user:

```
CREATE SESSION
UNLIMITED TABLESPACE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE CLUSTER
CREATE ANY VIEW
CREATE SEQUENCE
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE TRIGGER
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
CREATE TYPE
CREATE OPERATOR
CREATE INDEXTYPE
ADVISOR
ADMINISTER SQL TUNING SET
```

and the `UNLIMITED TABLESPACE` is what I want this user to escape from, I know I can run revoke to remove the privilege, how can we exclude such privilege from `RESOURCE`, so that my user cannot access table with same name on other SCHEMA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't included in the list of privileges [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authorization.htm#r45c1-t12) says come with `RESOURCE`; and it isn't listed in `DBA_SYS_PRIVS` for that either. But it is granted with `RESOURCE`, with 11gR2 anyway.

The documentation also says:

> **Note:** Oracle recommends that you design your own roles for database security rather than relying on this role. This role may not be created automatically by future releases of Oracle Database.

It's stated more forcefully later that you shouldn't be using it and that it will be deprecated in a future release.

So the obvious answer is not to use the `RESOURCE` role at all, but grant the privileges you do want directly instead:

```
GRANT CONNECT TO TEMP_USER;
-- GRANT RESOURCE TO TEMP_USER;
GRANT CREATE CLUSTER TO TEMP_USER
GRANT CREATE INDEXTYPE TO TEMP_USER
GRANT CREATE OPERATOR TO TEMP_USER
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO TEMP_USER
GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO TEMP_USER
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO TEMP_USER
GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO TEMP_USER
GRANT CREATE TYPE TO TEMP_USER
GRANT CREATE ANY VIEW TO TEMP_USER;
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY DATA_PUMP_DIR TO TEMP_USER;
GRANT advisor to TEMP_USER;
GRANT administer sql tuning set to TEMP_USER;
GRANT CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW to TEMP_USER;
```

Or create your own role, grant the privileges to that, and grant the role to your user - which is more manageable (but could have implications for stored PL/SQL; not that you should ever need to run DDL from PL/SQL). Either way, only grant the privileges that user really needs, which may be a subset of those from `RESOURCE`.

However, you said "so that my user cannot access table with same name on other SCHEMA". That isn't what `UNLIMITED TABLESPACE" does, it lets you create objects in any tablespace without needing a storage quota:

[From the docs again](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/users.htm#DBSEG10240):

> To permit a user to use an unlimited amount of any tablespace in the database, grant the user the `UNLIMITED TABLESPACE` system privilege. This overrides all explicit tablespace quotas for the user. If you later revoke the privilege, then you must explicitly grant quotas to individual tablespaces. You can grant this privilege only to users, not to roles.

You probably still don't want your user to have that privilege, but it only affects the storage they can use, not what they can access in other schemas.

`CREATE ANY VIEW` also looks a little out of place as that allows you to create a view in another schema; maybe you only meant to use `CREATE VIEW`.